# C# reversing Names

Tags: c#

I have to write a program were the user inputs the names (Aryah Stark, etc) and the otuput some to be Stark, Aryah.  I cant seem to figure out why my code isn't coming out that way though.  I know the Reverse. Array method but I don't know if I placing it right or not.  Can someone help me?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many names do you want to enter? ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        int arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(name);
        string[] LaName = new string[arraySize];
        Array.Reverse(LaName);

        for (int i = 0; i < LaName.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter last name");
            LaName[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        foreach (string val in LaName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val + "\t");                
        }

        Console.ReadKey();            
    }        
}
```

Comment: This code would work, if you put the reversing _after_ the read of your names. Do note, it's useless to add the \t if you do a writeLINE to the console in every iteration of that loop; the tabs will just be invisible at the end of each line. If you want them on _one_ line, I suggest you look into `String.Join(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx) reverses a sequence of elements.

Based on example, what you need is reversing of a words in a string, so `Split` the string to words and then use `Array.Reverse` to reverse the array.

You could try using either of these solutions, place this logic inside your for loop (after reading user input).

```
string[] words = LaName[i].Split(' ');
Array.Reverse(words);
LaName[i] = String.Join(" ", words);
```

or simply (.Net 3.5 and aboeve)

```
LaName[i] =String.Join(" ", LaName[i].Split(' ').Reverse());
```

Check this [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9QaXyw)

Comment: This helped! Thanks so much. I am just starting off in programming. I knew I had to use the Reverse method. I appreciate the help.